Xcode: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation
I am getting this error after updating Xcode.
    The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

It was working fine before the update.
I have tried both suggestions that the error suggests with no luck.

What is your cocoapods version? Also can you share your podfile? Might also be worth to share what the result is of running pod install.
